# static keyword when creating instance

Tags: c#

I came across the following code.

```
public class Test
{
  public static Test Create() 
  {
    return new Test 
    {
     a1 =1,
     b1="abc"     

    };
  }
  :
  :
  :
}
```

And in the calling class it is instantiated as below

```
static Test model = Test.Create();
```

What is the use of `static` keyword in the above line? What will be the difference if we don't use the `static` keyword? I'm using .NET 4 and VS 2010

**EDIT**

I know what is `static` in c#. The main reason I asked this question is why is it used when creating instance of class?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx - or read up on static fields in whichever book/tutorial you're learning C# from.

Comment: Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: see my answer on possible option for this...

Comment: @musefan I deleted my answer, because you made me realize I made a mistake.  I got my languages messed up.  It's not private by default.  My bad.

Comment: MSDN is not always the best place to direct people, yes it contains the information, but is not always the best at explaining it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this *concrete* presented code, don't see much sence of using this technique, but usually
you can do this in order to control your type instances creation.

For example: immagine that your class interacts with some COM object of the client, that can not be instantiated more the 10 times. To control that consumer of your API will not create more then 10 instances of your type, you can use this technique.

```
public class MyComWrapper {
  private  MyComWrapper () {} // MAKE CTOR PRIVATE SO NOONE CAN CREATE
                              // AN INSTANCE OF YOUR CLASS IF NOT WITH 
                              // `static` METHOD CALL

  static int counter = 0;           //INSTANCE COUNTER
  public static MyComWrapper Create() 
  {
    if(counter >10)       //MORE THEN 10, BAD !
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not instantiate more then 10 instances");

    counter ++;
    return new Test 
    {
     a1 =1,
     b1="abc"     

    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll find concrete example here http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Comment: @gmailuser: *probabbly* point here is that by using his static method you get an instance of that class with already all necessary properties field with predefined value. If you don't like that defaul values, or you want different startup configuration , just use ordinary instance creation way and fill properties with appropriate *to you* values.

Comment: @gmailuser: it looks like that was just a way to create an instance with some reasonable values for the demonstration. Perhaps the method should have been named `CreateExampleInstance`.

Answer (score 3):

The static keyword makes it available without instantiating the object.  The author is creating a function to instantiate the object in a specific way, but since it's the default constructor anyone can instantiate it.

Although not exclusively, along with making the constructor private, this is a pattern commonly used in the [Singleton Pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton).

Comment: How can you tell the constructor is private?

Answer (score 0):

`Static` modifier belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

You don't have to create an instance to use that [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) function. you can directly use the [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) function without creating an instance of the class.

If the static keyword is applied to a class, all the members of the class must be static.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. They are separate uses of `static`. The first one creates a static method in a non-static class. The second one create a static member of the "calling" class.

Your `Test` class itself is not static, so you are allowed to instantiate it.

To answer your question: if you do not use the `static` keyword in the calling class, it will be a "normal" instance member.